# Keep equal height textareas and buttons

Tags: jquery, html, events, resize, textarea

I am looking to set equal height of the two textareas and intervening button on load, then keep their heights synchronized throughout manual resizing. I would like pure query alternative. As bonus, it would be nice to auto expand/contract as text is entered/removed, again keeping other textarea and button synced. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

```css
#c, #d {
width: 40%;
resize:vertical;
min-height:100px;
max-height:500px;
vertical-align:top;
}

#bo {
    width: 10%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"><textarea id="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta recusandae animi dignissimos natus obcaecati error eveniet, repellendus tempora. Illum sint veniam impedit eaque nesciunt ipsam! Unde tempore nihil qui possimus?
Illum similique sequi quisquam nemo libero magni velit, aliquid esse perspiciatis. Sapiente ipsum voluptatem blanditiis animi dicta facilis, nesciunt, velit magnam pariatur consectetur eius voluptatibus praesentium asperiores veritatis dolor nihil?
Rem, veniam? Consectetur, odit at. Obcaecati aspernatur est quibusdam rem, vel ut deserunt nihil ex libero itaque pariatur adipisci cum magni dolores tempore nisi placeat ab aut culpa. Iure, fugit!
Ab, culpa deleniti? Beatae minima, debitis ea dolore hic praesentium minus obcaecati expedita iusto non, voluptatem ipsa cupiditate eligendi perspiciatis doloremque atque odio cum, cumque ipsam incidunt maxime. Architecto, perferendis.
</textarea><button id="bo">&lt&lt</button><textarea id="d"></textarea></div>
</body>
</html>
```

basd upon Rick Hitchcock's answer, I was able to make it work. My initial request was not detailed enough. His answer allowed me to get to wht I wanted below.

```js
  $('#content #c').on('input', function() {
    $('#content #c')
      .height(0) /* 0 to allow shrinking */
      .height($('#c').prop('scrollHeight')
             );
  }).trigger('input');
```

```css
#content {
display: flex;
}

#c,
#d {
  width: 45%;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 500px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden /* no scrollbars ie*/
}

#d {
  readOnly: true;
  background-color: LightGrey;
  outline: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

textarea {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#bo {
  width: 10%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"><textarea id="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta recusandae animi dignissimos natus obcaecati error eveniet, repellendus tempora. Illum sint veniam impedit eaque nesciunt ipsam! Unde tempore nihil qui possimus?
Illum similique sequi quisquam nemo libero magni velit, aliquid esse perspiciatis. Sapiente ipsum voluptatem blanditiis animi dicta facilis, nesciunt, velit magnam pariatur consectetur eius voluptatibus praesentium asperiores veritatis dolor nihil?
Rem, veniam? Consectetur, odit at. Obcaecati aspernatur est quibusdam rem, vel ut deserunt nihil ex libero itaque pariatur adipisci cum magni dolores tempore nisi placeat ab aut culpa. Iure, fugit!
Ab, culpa deleniti? Beatae minima, debitis ea dolore hic praesentium minus obcaecati expedita iusto non, voluptatem ipsa cupiditate eligendi perspiciatis doloremque atque odio cum, cumque ipsam incidunt maxime. Architecto, perferendis.
</textarea><button id="bo">&lt&lt</button><textarea id="d" readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta recusandae animi dignissimos natus obcaecati error eveniet, repellendus tempora. Illum sint veniam impedit eaque nesciunt ipsam! Unde tempore nihil qui possimus?
Illum similique sequi quisquam nemo libero magni velit, aliquid esse perspiciatis. Sapiente ipsum voluptatem blanditiis animi dicta facilis, nesciunt, velit magnam pariatur consectetur eius voluptatibus praesentium asperiores veritatis dolor nihil?
Rem, veniam? Consectetur, odit at. Obcaecati aspernatur est quibusdam rem, vel ut deserunt nihil ex libero itaque pariatur adipisci cum magni dolores tempore nisi placeat ab aut culpa. Iure, fugit!
Ab, culpa deleniti? Beatae minima, debitis ea dolore hic praesentium minus obcaecati expedita iusto non, voluptatem ipsa cupiditate eligendi perspiciatis doloremque atque odio cum, cumque ipsam incidunt maxime. Architecto, perferendis.ds
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta recusandae animi dignissimos natus obcaecati error eveniet, repellendus tempora. Illum sint veniam impedit eaque nesciunt ipsam! Unde tempore nihil qui possimus?
Illum similique sequi quisquam nemo libero magni velit, aliquid esse perspiciatis. Sapiente ipsum voluptatem blanditiis animi dicta facilis, nesciunt, velit magnam pariatur consectetur eius voluptatibus praesentium asperiores veritatis dolor nihil?
Rem, veniam? Consectetur, odit at. Obcaecati aspernatur est quibusdam rem, vel ut deserunt nihil ex libero itaque pariatur adipisci cum magni dolores tempore nisi placeat ab aut culpa. Iure, fugit!
Ab, culpa deleniti? Beatae minima, debitis ea dolore hic praesentium minus obcaecati expedita iusto non, voluptatem ipsa cupiditate eligendi perspiciatis doloremque atque odio cum, cumque ipsam incidunt maxime. Architecto, perferendis.ds
</textarea></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `content` a flex box, so all its children will be the same height:

```
#content {
  display: flex;
}
```

When you edit a textarea, set both textareas' heights to 0 to get scrollbars, then set both their heights to be the maximum of their scroll heights:

```
  $('#content textarea').on('input', function() {
    $('#content textarea')
      .height(0)
      .height(Math.max($('#c').prop('scrollHeight'),
                       $('#d').prop('scrollHeight')
                      )
             );
  }).trigger('input');
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content textarea').on('input', function() {
    $('#content textarea')
      .height(0)
      .height(Math.max($('#c').prop('scrollHeight'),
                       $('#d').prop('scrollHeight')
                      )
             );
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
#c,
#d {
  width: 40%;
  resize: vertical;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 500px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#bo {
  width: 10%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="content">
    <textarea id="c">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta recusandae animi dignissimos natus obcaecati error eveniet, repellendus tempora. Illum sint veniam impedit eaque nesciunt ipsam! Unde tempore nihil qui possimus?</textarea>
    <button id="bo">&lt&lt</button>
    <textarea id="d"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will do both the things for you in minimal line use [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) for auto resize and use the event `autosize:resized` to keep the other `textarea` height sync.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea#c'));

  $("#c").on('autosize:resized', function() {
    $("#d").height($("#c").outerHeight());
  });
  $("#d").height($("#c").outerHeight());

});
```

```css
#c,
#d {
  width: 40%;
  resize: vertical;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 500px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

textarea {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#bo {
  width: 10%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autosize@4.0.0/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <textarea id="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta recusandae animi dignissimos natus obcaecati error eveniet, repellendus tempora. Illum sint veniam impedit eaque nesciunt ipsam! Unde tempore nihil qui possimus?
Illum similique sequi quisquam nemo libero magni velit, aliquid esse perspiciatis. Sapiente ipsum voluptatem blanditiis animi dicta facilis, nesciunt, velit magnam pariatur consectetur eius voluptatibus praesentium asperiores veritatis dolor nihil?
Rem, veniam? Consectetur, odit at. Obcaecati aspernatur est quibusdam rem, vel ut deserunt nihil ex libero itaque pariatur adipisci cum magni dolores tempore nisi placeat ab aut culpa. Iure, fugit!
Ab, culpa deleniti? Beatae minima, debitis ea dolore hic praesentium minus obcaecati expedita iusto non, voluptatem ipsa cupiditate eligendi perspiciatis doloremque atque odio cum, cumque ipsam incidunt maxime. Architecto, perferendis.
</textarea>
  <button id="bo">&lt&lt</button>
  <textarea id="d"></textarea></div>
```